# Rank and rownumber functions are not working in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, rank, row-number

I have sqlite version:

SQLite 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53 884b4b7e502b4e991677b53971277adfaf0a04a284f8e483e2553d0f83156b50
zlib version 1.2.11
gcc-5.2.0

and when I try use Row number function like that:

```
select Country, Numbers,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (partition by Country ORDER BY Numbers DESC) RowNum
from Table
```

I got an error message:
Error: misuse of window function row_number()

as I understand sqlite is support those functions....
Some one has any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Your query works fine in SQLite 3.27.2

Comment: Is that your exact query you're running?